# How to get list of devices that are connected or disconnected to a specified wifi router

Tags: android, wifi

I am making an attendance tracker app and in that i want to show the list of devices connected or disconnected which will reflect the presence and absence of the employee to whosoever boss / manager/ director whatever.

Means, for an instance, say if the employee arrives at the office and connects to the office wifi then the boss will see that this employee is in the office. The restriction is that the boss will see the status only and only if the employee is connected to the office (specified) wifi router. And if the employee goes outside for a while or goes away then the boss will see that this device is disconnected means that the employee is not in the office or at his desk.

How do i accomplish this? I have read several topics on WifiManager and WifiP2pManager and similar but they are very overwhelming. Please help me on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching solution for this and tried lots of things.
After all search I follow @Ankita Solution and its works fine. But sometimes few devices are not showing in list.

Please have a look on below code I am using right now.

First of all fetch my own device IP address to check what subnet I have.This IP is used to ping other IPs.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
 txtView.append("My IP address: " + ipAddress);
        txtView.append("\n");


    btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    String text = edtIP.getText().toString();
                    if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                        subnet = text;
                    }

                    new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            int timeout = 100;
                            for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
                                String host = subnet + "." + i;
                                try {
                                    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                                    if (inetAddress.isReachable(timeout)) {
                                byte[] mac = null;
                                NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inetAddress);
                                if (ni != null) {
                                    mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
                                    if (mac != null) {
                                        for (int k = 0; k < mac.length; k++) {
                                            System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[k], (k < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Address doesn't exist or is not accessible.");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Network Interface for the specified address is not found.");
                                }
                                        Log.e(TAG, host + " is reachable");
                                        publishProgress(host + " is reachable \n" + inetAddress.toString());
                                    } else {
                                        publishProgress("host " + host + " is not reachable");
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }
                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                            txtView.append(((++counter) + ".") + " " + values[0]);
                            txtView.append("\n");
                            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                        }
                    }.execute();
                }
            });
```

Comment: It takes too much time If I have timeout 1000 milliseconds. While in Fing application takes not more than 5 seconds to list connected devices. If anyone have better solution, Please mention.